# angular-drag-and-drop-lists items in separate container

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I use the [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) directives to handle drag and drop operations. I populate groups separated from the actual items. Problems occurs when I drag the item onto the ul element, item disappears. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/CHQdHzHRSNiC1ZvNNZrG?p=preview) is a link to a plunker for you to be able to see what I mean.

Below is my code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="group in groups"
    class="groups"
    dnd-list="items">
  <li class="title">{{group.name}}</li>
</ul>

<ul class="items">
  <li class="item"
      ng-repeat="item in items"
      dnd-draggable="item"
      dnd-moved="items.splice($index, 1)"
      dnd-effect-allowed="move">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the documentation says that you need to set a dnd-list on the target one and also you'll need to render that list yourself:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9OTy70KZZwavIWClIgvY?p=preview

```
<ul ng-repeat="group in groups" dnd-list="group.items" class="groups">
    <li class="title">{{group.name}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in group.items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

and...

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
        name : 'Group 1',
        items: []
    },
    {
        name : 'Group 2',
        items: []
    },
    {
        name : 'Group 3',
        items: []
    }
];
```

Btw, I have to thank you for introducing me to this great library!

Comment: This is actually the case, thanks for the answer! I'm not sure why (in this case) groups must have items, even though they're empty, to be able to "receive" items from other list. Anyway, thanks again.